# How to modify Linked List Element Values Without Destroying the List

Tags: c, linked-list, scheduler

I am working on a First-Come-First-Serve Scheduler Algorithm in C using a linked list structure. I am encountering an issue when I try to perform the calculations needed on every Element of the Linked List. I cannot seem to figure out how to modify the values of the Linked List without destroying the list by iterating through it. Is there a good way to fix this?

To explain what the calculations I am doing are, here is an example.

```
process no. arrivalTime burstTime 
1           0           12
2           7           11
3           13          2
```

What I am doing is finding the completion time and waiting time for all the simulated processes when using this scheduling algorithm.

```
process no. waitingTime finishTime 
1           0           12   
2           5           23
3           10          25
```

The first set of loops essentially keeps track of the process turnaround time. I use this to solve finish and waiting times in the second loop set.

```
//Linked List struct
typedef struct process
{
    int processId;
    int arrivalTime;
    int burstTime;
    int ct;
    int waitingTime;
    int finishTime;
    int priorityValue;
    int turnAroundTime;
    struct process* next;
} process;

void firstComeFirstServed(process* list)
{
    int calc;
    process* temp1 = list;
    process* temp2 = list;
    while(temp1!=NULL)
    {
        calc=0;
        while(temp2!=NULL)
        {
            calc =  calc + temp2->burstTime;
            temp1->ct = calc;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        //Keep iterationg through List here. Not sure how to get changed Elements into orginal list without also breaking it
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    //Have not worked on this part yet, but probably has same issue
    while(list!=NULL)
    {
        list->finishTime = list->ct + list->burstTime;
        list->waitingTime = list->ct - list->arrivalTime;
    }
    //listHead is just a global variable list, so I just want to copy this at the end
    listHead = list;
}
```

Comment: It would also help if you provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This example should contain the definition of your linked list node data type, i.e. the definition of `struct process`.

Comment: I changed one of the numbers in the example input. You should review, and adjust if necessary.

Comment: Is the list sorted by the `arrivalTime`? If it is, you should be able to do all of the calculations in a single pass. Otherwise, you need to scan the list for the lowest arrival time, which doesn't seem to be what your code is doing.

Comment: `while(list!=NULL)`<<-- `the `list` variable is never modified inside this loop. This loop runs never or forever. Hint: use `for()` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to implement a *stack* (FIFO or FCFS data structure) In https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-a-stack-using-singly-linked-list/ is an example how to implement this using a singly linked list .

However because of your calculations i think that you have to rearrange the list nodes and you need to do this **in-place**  (You are required to do this in-place without altering the nodes’ values (or destroying the list))

Example code for rearranging a linked list *in-place* is in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-a-given-linked-list-in-place/ or in the discussion of https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-list/

Alternatively you could implement the scheduler as a *heap* what is a common implementation for a scheduler (https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc-stable/node33.html). After the calculations (wait_time,...) build the heap using i.e. `heap sort`, code is in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/